# Azure CDN - Custom Domain SSL via Resource Management API

Tags: powershell, dns, azure-resource-manager, azure-cdn, azure-sdk

Using the latest [Azure Powershell SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WindowsAzurePowershellGet.3f.3f.3fnew.appids), but still can't seem to [create Custom SSL Domains for CDNs in Azure via API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl). We have 100s of subdomains to create and need to be able to script the creation of this task for future extensibility.

[image]

Does anyone know how to toggle this flag via the REST API since the [SDK has no support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.cdn/v2.7.0/new-azurermcdnendpoint)? We are using the [`New-AzureRmCdnCustomDomain` commandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.cdn/new-azurermcdncustomdomain?view=azurermps-3.7.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The AzureRM 6.13.0-module and the new Az-modules (including Az.Cdn) now supports this using a cmdlet. See [Enable-AzureCdnCustomDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.cdn/enable-azurermcdncustomdomain?view=azurermps-6.13.0) (AzureRM.Cdn) or Enable-AzCdnCustomDomain (Az.Cdn)

---

The REST API for enabling Custom Domain HTTPS is documented at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/customdomains#CustomDomains_EnableCustomHttps)

> **Enable Custom Https**
>
> Enable https delivery of the custom domain.
>
> ```
> POST /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/{profileName}/endpoints/{endpointName}/customDomains/{customDomainName}/enableCustomHttps?api-version=2017-10-12
> ```

Before you can use the Azure REST API you need to get [an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-rest-api):

> **Generating access token using PowerShell:**
>
> ```
> $Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{
>     "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
>     "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
>     "client_id" = "<application id>"
>     "client_secret" = "<password you selected for authentication>"
> }
> ```
>
> The response contains an access token, information about how long that
>   token is valid, and information about what resource you can use that
>   token for. The access token you received in the previous HTTP call
>   must be passed in for all request to the Resource Manager API. You
>   pass it as a header value named "Authorization" with the value "Bearer
>   YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN". Notice the space between "Bearer" and your access
>   token.

Client ID is retrived by creating an app registration in Azure AD and the clientkey is generated in the Keys-section of the created app registration. This can be combined into a solution like this:

```
$subscriptionId = "..."
$resourceGroupName = "..."
$profileName = "..."
$endpointName = "..."
$customDomainName = ".."

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{
    "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
    "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
    "client_id" = "<application id>"
    "client_secret" = "<password you selected for authentication>"
}

$header = @{
     "Authorization"= "Bearer $($Token.access_token)"
 }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $header -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/$profileName/endpoints/$endpointName/customDomains/$customDomainName/enableCustomHttps?api-version=2016-10-02"
```

If you don't need to automate the script, you can login manually using GUI (no need for app-registration) using this modified sample (based on [Source](https://marckean.com/2016/09/08/using-the-azure-rest-api-in-powershell-asm-arm/)). It requires [AzureRM](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases)-module, which can be installed using `Install-Module AzureRM`:

```
Function Login-AzureRESTApi {

    Import-Module AzureRM.Profile

    # Load ADAL Azure AD Authentication Library Assemblies
    $modulepath = Split-Path (Get-Module -Name AzureRM.Profile).Path
    $adal = "$modulepath\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
    $adalforms = "$modulepath\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll"
    $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal)
    $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms)

    # Login to Azure
    $Env = Login-AzureRmAccount

    # Select Subscription
    $Subscription = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title "Choose a subscription ..." -PassThru)
    $adTenant = $Subscription.TenantId
    $global:SubscriptionID = $Subscription.SubscriptionId

    # Client ID for Azure PowerShell
    $clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

    # Set redirect URI for Azure PowerShell
    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

    # Set Resource URI to Azure Service Management API | @marckean
    $resourceAppIdURIASM = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
    $resourceAppIdURIARM = "https://management.azure.com/"

    # Set Authority to Azure AD Tenant
    $authority = "https://login.windows.net/$adTenant"

    # Create Authentication Context tied to Azure AD Tenant
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

    # Acquire token
    $global:authResultASM = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURIASM, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")
    $global:authResultARM = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURIARM, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")

} 

$resourceGroupName = "..."
$profileName = "..."
$endpointName = "..."
$customDomainName = ".."

Login-AzureRESTApi

#Reuse selected subscription from login
$Subscription = $global:subscriptionId

$header = @{
     "Authorization"= $global:authResultARM.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
 }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $header -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/$profileName/endpoints/$endpointName/customDomains/$customDomainName/enableCustomHttps?api-version=2017-10-12"
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could update this for the latest versions of AzureRM and Az modules please. MS have been moving the goal posts, yet again! Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming it's to do with MS changing things, although I've gone right back to version 2.8.0 of AzureRM.Profile, I still get [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext] does not contain a method named 'AcquireToken'. I've gone right back to AzureRm.Profile version 2.8.0.

Comment: Looks like you finally got a Cmdlet for this in the latest AzureRm.Cdn module that you should try. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.cdn/enable-azurermcdncustomdomain?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: The cmdlet is called `Enable-AzCdnCustomDomain` in the new Az-modules (which replaces AzureRm)